# Laravel 4 DB::table - Foreach

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to run a sql query and return all values into an array of the tables names...

This is what I have so far:

```
$vehiclemodeldata = DB::table('model')->where('model_id', $viewData['model_id'])->get();
$row = $vehiclemodeldata->row();
foreach ($row as $key => $value){

   $viewData['vehiclemodeldata_'.$key]= $value;

}
```

What are your throughts?

**EDIT**

I've tried this it seems to bring it back in an array but I can't access the array for some reason.

```
$VehicleModel = DB::table('model')->where('model_id', $viewData['model_id'])->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `$vehiclemodeldata = DB::table('model')->where('model_id', $viewData['model_id'])->get();` actually returns an object instead of an array.

Your `foreach` loop is correct. You can later access properties in the array by using syntax like this `$viewData['vehiclemodeldata_1']->yourProperty;` which is used to access properties of objects.

Hope it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$vehiclemodeldata = DB::table('model')->where('model_id', $viewData['model_id'])->first();
$viewData['vehiclemodeldata'] = $vehicle->toArray();
```

But why would you like to do this?
I would pass query result directly to view instead

```
$vehicle = DB::table('model')->where('model_id', $id)->first();

return View::make('whateverview', compact('vehicle'));

// view file
Model: {{ $vehicle->model }}
...
```

Comment: I need to assign the query to variables to use throughout the controller and not pass it to the view.

Comment: Then, your variable naming makes no sense... :)